# CSS appears to be off in careers candidate profiles (employer view)

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

I've seen it happen a few times that the "Top Answers" section of a candidate's profile (while looking as the employer) have the bottom-borders offset because the repeated divs have padding but no size.

[image: Titles and tags obscured to protect the innocent]

The `<div class="-row answer repeater...>` element seems to be where the problem is, and I think this can be fixed with something like `min-height`.  I've set `min-height: 75px` in the `.cv .repeater` rule, and this is the result:

[image: still protecting the innocent...]

There is probably more than one way to skin this cat, but this seemed like the lowest hanging fruit to me.

Comment: -1: no relevant code ;)

Comment: Hey there, I can't reproduce this on Windows using Chrome 40, Firefox 35, or IE 11, nor on OS X using Chrome 40 or Safari 8. Are you still experiencing this? What browser/OS are you using? And to be clear, this is via the Candidate Search interface?

Comment: @Mike, This is the candidate profile view, arrived via direct link (i.e., `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/jobs/###/candidates#!/profile/###`).  I still see this on both my machines.  One is OSX (Yosemite) + Chrome 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit), the other is Windows 8.1 + Chrome 41.0.2272.35 beta-m (64-bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice catch! Fix is going out shortly.